# Is it possible to force PhpStorm autocompletion to show only fields or only methods available to an object?

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

It happens when working with objects that we want to get access only to fields (or methods) available but the rest overshadows our needs in autocompletion.

It would be really convienient if I could force PhpStorm autocompletion to show me only fields (or methods) available to an object.

Unfortunately I didnt find any solution for that.

Comment: Show fields only or methods only? Nope.

Comment: Thats a pity! :(